# Unable to send data from MainViewController to ContainerView with delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uicontainerview

I created simple ipad app, I want to send value from MainViewController to ContainerViewController.  My whole aim to this app send value from Container(A) to MainViewController and then MainViewController to Container(B). I am able to send value from Container(A) to MainViewController but I am not able to send data from MainViewController to Container(B). I think my usage of prepareForSegue is wrong. ? I've added image to describe my situation.

Thanks in advance.

**A_ContainerViewController.h**

```
@class A_ContainerVC;
@protocol A_ContainerVCDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)sendValue:(NSString *)Name;
@end

@interface A_ContainerViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,assign) id <A_ContainerVCDelegate> delegate

- (IBAction)btnSend:(id)sender;

@end
```

**A_ContainerViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)btnSend:(id)sender {

    NSString *text=@"Tutorial";

    [self.delegate sendValue:text];

}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "A_ContainerViewController.h"

@class MainVC;
@protocol MainVCDelegate <NSObject>  

-(void)sendValue2:(NSString *)Name;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,assign) id <MainVCDelegate> delegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblVC;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController () <A_ContainerVCDelegate>

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"A"]) {


        [(A_ContainerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];

    } 
}


-(void)sendValue:(NSString *)Name{

    lblVC.text = Name;
    [self.delegate sendValue2:Name];

}
```

**B_ContainerViewController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "A_ContainerViewController.h"
    @interface B_ContainerViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_B_VC;
@end
```

**B_ContainerViewController.m**

```
    @interface B_ContainerViewController ()<MainVCDelegate>
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"B"]) {


            [(ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];

            /*
             LayersViewController *layersViewController = (LayersViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
             layersViewController.name=@"Deneme";
             */


        }

    }

-(void)sendValue2:(NSString *)Name{

    lbl_B_VC.text=Name;

}
```

[image]

Comment: did you check whether delegate not nil? I'm assuming you call delegate method when click on button on controller A, meanwhile delegate of controller B is set on -prepareForSegue method which is not executed yet.

Comment: First of all I think you should change your syntax.

Comment: @kayzersoze Why should I change my syntax. I don't understand

Comment: @fozoglu it just a suggestion, if your syntax clear your code more readable easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

From your storyboard, Control Drag IBOutlets of both A and B controllers into the main one. Then, in the viewDidLoad method of MainViewController, set both delegates of the containers A and B to self.

Answer (score 1):

In B_ContainerViewController.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"B"]) {


        [(ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];

        /*
         LayersViewController *layersViewController = (LayersViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
         layersViewController.name=@"Deneme";
         */


    }

}
```

Why is this code inside B_ContainerViewController.m? Because if I understand your scenerio correctly, you have A and B Container VCs added inside `ViewController` class. So you should add B as delegate in prepareForSegue of `ViewController.m`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"A"]) 
    {
        [(A_ContainerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];    
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"B"])
    {
        self.delegate = (B_ContainerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;//B should conform to MainVCDelegate
    } 
}
```

Comment: I try code. Xcode give me This error at the ViewController.m -> Assignning to assigning to id <MainVCDelegate> from incompatible type 'B_ContainerViewControlle'

Comment: Make B_ContainerViewController conform MainVCDelegate
@interface B_ContainerViewController : UIViewController <MainVCDelegate>

Comment: Yes,I did but not change warning. This Full code  [link](https://gist.github.com/fozoglu/2350a45d2bb53a97e69b)

Comment: checked the code, you have added the <MainVCDelegate> to anonymous extension which is inside your .m file. You need to that in your .h file. So that other classes would know that your B_ContainerViewController conforms to a certain protocol.

Comment: sorry, I'm confused too . Can you explain from the beginning step by step ?

Comment: Solution:
In https://gist.github.com/fozoglu/2350a45d2bb53a97e69b#file-b_containerviewcontroller-h change line 5 to: @interface B_ContainerViewController : UIViewController <MainVCDelegate>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72396/discussion-between-taha-and-fozoglu).

Answer (score 0):

Here there is something that I wouldn't see...
This is a wrong use of the delegate pattern! If you want to pass a value to another `UIViewController` you have to save a reference to it in the other one. Then you can specify a public method in the `.h` file and call it from the other controllers.

For example, in **B_ContainerViewController**:

```
// .h file
@interface B_ContainerViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *labelTextValue;
@end
// .m file
@interface B_ContainerViewController ()
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_B_VC;
}
@end
@implementation
@synthesize labelTextValue = _labelTextValue;
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"B"]) 
    {

        /*
         LayersViewController *layersViewController = (LayersViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
         layersViewController.name=@"Deneme";
         */
    }

}

-(void)setLabelTextValue:(NSString *)labelTextValue
{
     _labelTextValue = labelTextValue;
    [lbl_B_VC setText: _labelTextValue];
}
```

So, in the controller **A**, on IBAction, you have to do this:

```
referenceToControllerB.labelTextValue = @"TEXT";
```

Comment: I try you said, I have revised my code . What should I write referenceToControllerB because not found object error.

Comment: If you don't want create a circular reference, you have to define a "super" object (I think it is `ViewController`). Now think about your code/segue flow. Maybe it is better if your AContainerController delegates ViewController. Then, in the ViewController store a reference to B_ContainerController and set its property.

Comment: I don't know how to do your last recommendation with code

Comment: This is my full code [link](https://gist.github.com/fozoglu/2350a45d2bb53a97e69b)